# Timestamps are appearing mid-line. How do I tell if it is my read or my write that is causing the issue?

Tags: python, logging, pyserial

I am currently trying to log data from a serial connection. I am using the python module [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/).

After reading a line from the serial connection, I want to prepend a timestamp to it, then write it to a file.

This works most of the time, but sometimes the timestamp appears in the file mid-line. Nowhere near an endline character.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
self.serialconnection = serial.Serial(port=self.port, baudrate=115200,
                                      timeout=0)
def run(self):
 openfile = open(self.logfile, 'a')
 while not self.stoprequest.isSet():
  try:
    linefromserial = self.serialconnection.readline()
    if linefromserial:
      linefromserial = linefromserial.replace('\00', '')
      datenow = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S   ")
      dated_linefromserial = datenow + linefromserial
      openfile.write(dated_linefromserial)
  except self.stoprequest.isSet():
    openfile.close()
    break
```

I am not using a timeout for the serial connection as I am running this in a separate thread, and I don't want it to block.

So is there any glaring issues with this method? How do I go about determining if the issue is with the readline() method failing to function as I envisioned, or if it is an issue with the file write?

Answer (score 1):

You are relying on the data from the serial line to contain newlines, you never write your own. It may be that the serial data contains carriage returns (often interpreted in the same way as newlines) as well, you'd need to clean those out.

Remove the carriage returs from the serial data (optional), and add an explicit newline when you write:

```
linefromserial = linefromserial.rstrip('\n').replace('\00', '').replace('\r', '')
datenow = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
openfile.write('%s   %s\n' % (datenow, linefromserial))
```

Now you always write a newline at the end of each received line (even if the readline() call didn't return one), and you are certain that no `\r` carriage return caused a line break elsewhere.

Comment: I was considering that, I will try it.
However I am sceptical, as the timestamps are appearing in the middle of words where there'd be no reason for a carriage return or a newline.

Comment: I suspect that the buffer runs empty when attempting to read a line from the serial port, thus you end up with partial lines. In which case the newlines you manually insert will at least let you know that the data came in in multiple reads.

Comment: This method has tidied up the log, there are no timestamps mid line anymore. However the read is still coming in two parts.

I've looked at the code for the readline function and it appears that it should not return at all unless the EOL or a timeout is reached.

Comment: @user1322388: then keep reading until you reach a newline; sometimes your buffer doesn't contain a newline for `.readline()` to read up to.

Comment: I thought the readline should of kept reading until a newline as the timeout was set to zero. I'm not entirely sure why but using the enhanced serial class described [here](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#wrapper-class). I have been able to resolve the issue. I'll look into it some more to discover the explanation then post the answer if I can figure it out.

p.s. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting your timeout to 0.
This means that when you perform the readline(), it will read whatever data is already in the buffer, but will not wait for an eol.

According to the PySerial API documentation for readline()
http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.FileLike.readline

"Read a line which is terminated with end-of-line (eol) character (\n by default) or until timeout."

You say you're running this in a separate thread, so it's not clear why you don't want it to block.

A possible solution would be to keep track whether the previous read was terminated by eol, and only then prepend the timestamp to the current read.

Another solution is to store the fragments you read until you receive one with eol, then assemble the fragments into a whole line, prepend your timestamp and write to the logfile.